# Calling a method on self while in dealloc

Tags: objective-c, dealloc

I have a dictionary of objects that need to be cleaned up before they are released.  I have a method that does this for the entire dictionary.  Before I release the dictionary in my `-dealloc` method, I want to do the same thing.  However, I am not sure of the state of the object during deallocation.  In C# or Java, for instance, I would never call a method on the object being finalized, but I am not sure this applies to Objective C and deallocation.  Is it acceptable to call the clean up method on `self` during deallocation, or should I duplicate that functionality in my `-dealloc`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you may invoke methods from inside your `dealloc` method, though you're wise to be cautious.  Pretty much the *only* methods you should invoke should be "tear down" methods, or methods that help in cleaning up an object before its resources are reclaimed.  Some of these cleanup methods include:

- unregistering for notifications via a notification center
- removing yourself as a key-value observer
- other general cleanup methods

Note, however, that in each of these methods, your object will be in an inconsistent state.  It may be partially deallocated (some ivars may/will be invalid), and so you should *never* rely on a specific object state.  These methods should *only* be used to continue deconstructing object state.

This is the fundamental reason why we're discouraged from using property setters (`setFoo:` methods) in `dealloc`: another object may be registered as an observer, and using the property will trigger a KVO notification, and if the observer is expect the object to have a valid state, they could be out of luck and things can blow up very quickly.

TL;DR:

Yes, it's safe, as long as you're smart about it.

Comment: Nice, thanks Dave.  That's exactly what I wanted to call: a tear-down method with no side effects.  But I am nervous about potential future refactoring adding responsibility to that method.  I can guarantee I know what it's doing now, but sometimes future me can be dumb. Maybe I just talked myself out of it.

Comment: @Don: A tear-down method is perfectly fine, especially if it helps further the DRY principle.

Comment: would it be advisable to call a method that closes a database connection or deletes temporary files in -dealloc or is there a more appropriate place for such things?

Comment: @dreyln that seems like a reasonable thing to do in `dealloc`

Comment: Database connections etc. should have been closed down earlier, because there is no guarantee when exactly dealloc is going to be called. There isn't even a guarantee that dealloc is called at all (if you quit an application, all the objects just disappear without dealloc being called).