# Release or set to nil retained members

Tags: objective-c, release, retain

Is it better to set my retained member vars to nil or to release them when I am cleaning up? Setting a retained var to nil seems a safer way to release an object without risking a double release call on it.

Update: Let me elaborate that I'm referring to member vars that have been set to have the retain property i.e.:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) SomeClass* mInstanceVar;
```

Comment: Hey Joey, if I've answered your question, don't forget to mark my answer as the correct one! ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's best practice to release your instance variables first, and then set them to `nil` in your `-dealloc` method. I personally like doing that like so:

```
[myVar release], myVar = nil;
```

If you set your instance variables to `nil`, you're not releasing them, and you're causing a memory leak. Setting them to `nil` after releasing though will ensure that you're not causing leaks, and if, for some reason, you try to access those instance variables later, you're not going to get garbage memory.

---

If you have an instance variable set up as such,

```
@property (retain) NSObject *myVar;
```

then it is not a good idea to call `self.myVar = nil;` during deallocation. If you have objects that have registered for KVO notifications on your instance variable, calling `self.myVar = nil` will send those notifications, and other objects will be notified, which is bad because they will be expecting you to still be in a valid state—you're not if you're in the deallocation process.

Even if they're not registered for KVO notifications, it's still not a good idea to do that because you should never call methods that could rely on your object's state when its state is inconsistent (some variables might/will be nonexistent), and you should simply handle the process yourself. `[myVar release], myVar = nil;` will suffice.

If you want more information, read Dave DeLong's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094615/calling-a-method-on-self-while-in-dealloc) question.

---

For initializing, it is also not good to call property setters and getters (for much the same reason as above). In an `-init` call, you would set up the aforementioned variable as such:

```
myVar = nil; // If you want to set it up as nil.
OR
myVar = [[NSObject alloc] init]; // Or set it up as an actual object.
```

Avoid `self.myVar = nil` and `self.myVar = [[NSObject alloc] init` in cases where your class is in an undeterminate state (these calls are fine in `-viewDidLoad` and `-awakeFromNib`, though, because by that point, your class has been completely initialized, and you can rely on the instance variables to be in a complete state).

Comment: I'm either confused still or I may have phrased the question incorrectly. I meant to say if I have a retain property set on my instance variable. I'll update the question to reflect that. If your response here was pertaining to this case, can you elaborate? My understanding was that a var with the retain property would retain an object upon setting with '=' and then when I do = nil; it would release that object. *That* is the case I'm asking about here.

Comment: I've updated my explanation. If it's still not clear, let me know and I'll add to it.

Comment: I think I understand your explanation. Is it then appropriate, with view controllers, to set cleaned up vars with the retain property '= nil' in the viewDidLoad method, but instead use [var release] in dealloc? (This is what I'm observing in their examples such as the ToolbarSearch example.)

Comment: In the `-viewDidLoad` method, it's fine to use property setters and getters because your class is completely initialized by then. However, it's not a good idea to do so during `-init` calls for the same reason as `dealloc` calls. I've updated my answer.

Comment: and if you're really lazy, there is a Three20 macro for doing the release/nil step... if you're not using Three20, then just write your own macro to do it.#define TT_RELEASE_SAFELY(__POINTER) { [__POINTER release]; __POINTER = nil; }

Comment: To whoever down-voted my answer, I would appreciate knowing why. If there's a problem in my answer, I'd like to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only accessing the values by way of the property accessors, simply set the property to `nil` and it will release.

Make sure to set all your properties to `nil` during `dealloc` as well.