# iOS Memory leaks

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have read that dealloc for an object will be called, only if retain count of that object becomes zero.

I am taking one object for `UIColor` in interface section and setting property

```
UIColor *currentColor;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *currentColor;
```

After using this object in the implemetation section, I am calling release method for this object in `dealloc`

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [currentColor release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

I am in doubt how `dealloc` will be called for this object, because I am not releasing the retained object anywhere. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have read that dealloc for an object will be called, only if retain
>   count of that object becomes zero.

Yes.

For the sake of simplicity, call the class that contains `currentColor` object as `ColorContainer`. Now, if you create an instance of `ColorContainer` like the following:

```
ColorContainer* containerColor = [[ColorContainer alloc] init]; // retain count + 1
```

the retain count for `containerColor` becomes 1.

Suppose you create an instance of a `UIColor` and you set that instance to `currentColor` property. In this case you can follow two different ways.
In the first one you can create an  instance like the following. If you use an instance method like `initWithRed:green:blue:alpha:` you have to release memory explicitly.

```
UIColor color* = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1]; // retain count + 1
containerColor.currentColor = color; // retain count +1, the referenced object has a retain count of 2 because you use a retain policy
[color release]; // retain count -1, now  the referenced object has a retain count of 1
```

In the second way, instead, you could use a class method (+ symbol). In this case you don't need to release memory explicity because the object created in that class method will be autoreleased at a certain point of your application lifetime.

```
containerColor.currentColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; // retain count +1
```

Now suppose you release `containerColor` object. If the retain count for `containerColor` is equal to 1, releasing it from an object that uses it, it enables to call its dealloc method and, in consequence, to dismiss also the object referenced by `currentColor`.

In this simple case study you have to note that the object referenced by `currentColor` is completely removed from memory (dismissed) only if it has a retain count of 1. In fact, if you do this

```
UIColor color* = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1]; // retain count + 1
containerColor.currentColor = color; // retain count +1, the referenced object has a retain count of 2
//[color release];
```

you create a memory leak (Do you understand way?).

To summarize, when you use `retain`, `copy`, `init` or `new` (it's the same of `alloc-init`), you have always to call their counterparts `release` or `autorelease`.

As a rule of thumb, you need always to balance the retain count for objects to avoid memory leaks.

So, as a methaphor you could think to memory like a tree. Suppose you have a parent (`containerColor`) and a child (`currentColor`). If the parent (with a retain of count of 1) is released, it causes to call its dealloc method and free memory for its object. If in its dealloc method you release a child (with a retain count of 1) it causes to call its dealloc method and free memory. In the case a child has a retain count greater than one, you cause a memory leak.

Hope it helps.

**Edit**

For further information you could read [About Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html). Since iOS 5 Apple has introduced ARC. Automatic Reference Counting is a compiler machanism that provides automatic memory management of Objective-C objects. For info see [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html).

Answer (score 2):

When you use retain setter for currentColor property you `retain` that object, and if you `retain` , `copy` or `alloc` memory for a object you MUST RELEASE IT. `-(void)dealloc` is the best place to do it

Answer (score 0):

You should only call `release` on the object if you allocated it (via `alloc`, `copy` or `retain`). Properties with the `retain` attribute will automatically do the memory management for you as long as you handle them properly, e.g. only access them via `self.currentColor`. Depending on how you created the color object you might or might not use `release` but you *always* should set the property to `nil` in your dealloc method. Two examples:

```
// If you use this (or some other way to get the color without alloc, copy or retain)
// then you do not need to do any release
self.currentColor = UIColor.blackColor;
self.currentColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.5 blue:0.2 alpha:1.0];

// On the other hand if you get it like this, you have to release/autorelease the object
self.currentColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0 green:0.5 blue:0.2 alpha:1.0];
[self.currentColor release];
// or better
self.currentColor = [[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0 green:0.5 blue:0.2 alpha:1.0] autorelease];

// dealloc always the same
-(void)dealloc{
    [currentColor release], currentColor = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

There are two important facts here:

1. For each `alloc`, `copy` or `retain` that your code issues, you have to issue `release` or `autorelease`.
2. Always use `self.currentColor` to access the property and not `currentColor` except when deallocating. The thing here is that when using `self.currentColor` the system automatically adds memory management code. Whenever `self.currentColor` is set, it automatically `retain`s and `release`s the objects. Only on final deallocation you should set the variable directly, for more information see [this answer on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5358254/605221) (thanks to Flex_Addicted).

Comment: Calling `self.currentColor = nil;` in dealloc method could create problems as suggested in [release-or-set-to-nil-retained-members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358134/release-or-set-to-nil-retained-members) and in [MemoryMgmt Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW1)

Comment: Thanks, quite an interesting thought. I'll edit my post accordingly.