# What does it mean to declare IBOutlet in @interface?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iboutlet

What's does it mean to declare IBOutlet in `@interface` vs not?  In a simple test, the assignment works in either case.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
    NSString *string;
    /*IBOutlet*/ UILabel *total;//What does it mean to declare IBOutlet here?
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *total;
```

`.h`

```
@synthesize total;
total.text = @"23";
```

Comment: It allows you to use the declared element in Interface Builder (IB = Interface Builder)

Comment: How is that the case? As I stated in the OP, I am able to use the declared element in IB with or without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the ivar will be an IBOutlet. Just like your current property is an IBOutlet.

You're making a bigger mistake in naming your ivar and property the same thing.

`total.text` and `self.total.text` in your file are not the same thing.

Comment: Where should I correct the property mistake?  Do you mean I create a new variable when I call `@synthesize`?  Kiddie words please, I am still working on hello world for iphone.

Comment: common practice is to call your property `total` and your ivar `_total` that way you can't mix them up. You can do something like `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *total;` and `@synthesize total = _total;` And you can get rid of the interface declaration in this case all together.

Answer (score 3):

The term `IBOutlet` is only a placeholder for Xcode. By means of it, Xcode helps you to connect an instance variable to a graphical element.

Here my previous old answer for it: [iOS Memory Management Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055926/ios-memory-management-issue).

Take a look. It covers a lot of stuff.

I also suggest to read [nib-memory-management](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-04-13-nib-memory-management.html) by **Mike Ash**.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference for IB, however, with your property in place, your `UILabel` gets retained and you must release it (if you aren't using ARC). If you don't use the `@property`, the label isn't owned by you and you don't need to release it.