# Last method to be called consistently in an iOS class?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In an iOS class that will not appear as a view e.g.

```
@interface MyDataClass : NSObject{}
```

Is there a method that can be overridden and is consistently called at the end of the classes' execution/lifecycle similar to `viewDidUnload` or `dealloc`, that can call methods safely?

Alternatively how would one go about implementing a method that could recognise the completion of the useful lifespan of such a class?

Comment: dealloc is used for this purpose. why won't use that?

Comment: Please, read something about your programming language before you start program in it. The `dealloc` method is mentioned in the first chapter of every obj-c tutorial.

Comment: @Sulthan: This isn't what my intent was when asking my question, although on reflection it isn't particularly succinct.

Comment: Please tell us what you want to accomplish. It's very hard to answer this generic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean a method that runs at the end of lifetime of the **Class** as a whole (not an instance), I wonder how is the runtime supposed to know when you are done using a class (you can create new instances at any time)? There is an `+initialize` method, but technically the class itself is available forever (until the program exits).

If you mean the lifetime of an instance, the method you are looking for is `-dealloc`.

-dealloc is called whenever an object's internal reference count reaches zero. In non-ARC code, if you override it you must call the superclass' implementation, so that ultimately `NSObject`'s `-dealloc` is called and that is when the memory is freed.

EDIT: Regarding low memory situations, this is how you register for notifications:

```
// Somewhere inside the -init method of your class
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(myMethod:) 
                                             name:UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

Inside dealloc, you MUST do this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

...otherwise, your app may crash.

And of course, you must implement a method with the following signature that will be called on low-memory situations:

```
- (void) myMethod:(NSNotification*) notification
{
   // Do some cleanup here, perhaps.
}
```

(otherwise, your app will crash)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this, I think it will be very helpful.

Comment: It would also be best if instead of calling the listener method 'myMethod:', you give it a meaningful name, hopefully related to the notification it listens to (in this case, e.g. -applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:)

Answer (score 3):

I believe dealloc is the last method that's get called if an NSObject subclass is released from memory.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% certain yet, but is "`dealloc`" still called at all in the case of ARC being turned on?

Comment: Dealloc is called even in ARC. If your old, non-ARC dealloc only releases ivars and calls super, you don't need to implement it explicitly in ARC. But you can have an empty dealloc (without calling super, which is forbidden) and do your custom cleanup there (like calling free() on C pointers, etc.)

Comment: Should be. Let's see if I can find a link.

Comment: On reflection my question isn't very well worded. My understanding is that dealloc is reserved solely for releasing various objects allocated to memory; I'm looking for something that can call a method which will vary on a previously user determined set of variables.

Comment: Your comment is still very vague. Dealloc gets called on **every** object (that inherits from NSObject) on deletion. Think of something similar (but not identical) to a destructor.

Answer (score 2):

like

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}
```

?

Comment: Exactly what I thought (misunderstood?) See my answer

Comment: I'm more looking for something like viewDidUnload or a method by which a class can identify the end of its useful lifespan. Or am I over-thinking this too much and stciking method calls in dealloc is perfectly acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine you want to have a different method, other than `dealloc`, called on low memory conditions (not when the object is deallocated). Which object would call that method?

`viewDidUnload` is part of the UI Framework and it is called by it. When the application gets a message about low memory conditions, the framework just redirects the message to all active view controllers.

You can implement the same by creating a method on your custom class, e.g. `-(void)onLowMemory` and then call it from you application delegate from `applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning` method or you can register the class to listen to `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification`.

Comment: This answer is more inline with what I was asking in the original question but would a method like this that imitates viewDidUnload, be an apt place to call a method that varies its scope and result based on user defined parameters that are passed to it?

Comment: Your question is still incromprehensible. You have to summarize clearly what you want to do and edit the question. I suppose it is more of an architecture problem

Comment: If you want to do something on low memory warning situations (like the app delegate and view controllers do), you can register any object to observe the pertinent notification, using NSNotificationCenter

Comment: @ranReloaded Please don't write comments not related to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094615/calling-a-method-on-self-while-in-dealloc) more or less answers my question, but not entirely. I think my question has more to do with architecture or method procurement and procedure as opposed to something that can be answered simply.

Comment: @ranReloaded: Your mention of NSNotificationCenter is something I'm now looking in to, thanks.

Comment: Check this notification: 'UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification'